# passing a numeric value in a variable field to Paypal via form and input tag

Tags: paypal

I am trying to pass a numeric value (monetary) to Paypal via the normal form and input tags. In my other pages the value is selected from a list via radio buttons but in this new page the amount is going to vary depending upon a number of selections in other stages so will vary from payment to payment.

I'm stumped at what to use to do this even having read most of the results form the "similar questions" above.

I'm using asp.net/VS to design and build my website. Any simple example(s) would be appreciated.

Comment: The old PayPal Payments Standard, https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/create-payment-button/ , is a deprecated legacy integration and should not be used for anything new. See the current standard integration guide, which uses a JS SDK and API calls https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/

Comment: That being said that doesn't really answer my question. Even if it wasn't being used with paypal I'd still like to know HOW to pass a value from a database field or string/int/decimal in my code to the value= field of an input tag.